# How to cancel a crowdloan before its ending block?

Tags: parachain, crowdloan

I want to cancel a crowdloan before its ending block and find there are `crowdloan.refund` and `crowdloan.dissolve` extrinsics.

Can I use `crowdloan.refund` or `crowdloan.dissolve` extrinsic to cancel a crowdloan? If not, is there any way to cancel a crowdloan before it ends? Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

their is a `edit` call to change the end date of the fund, authorized only to sudo